open image file in K6 is failing
im facing beloww error ech time i run my code that read image in K6 , i need help
error i get
Value is not an object: undefined
    at file:/tests/load/src/captainRegistration/uploadDocuments.js:7:23(39)
    at go.k6.io/k6/js.(*requireImpl).require-fm (native)
    at file:/tests/load/src/captainRegistration/captainSignUp.js:2:0(23)
    at go.k6.io/k6/js.(*requireImpl).require-fm (native)
    at file:/tests/load/test.js:4:0(34)  hint="script exception"

my code
import http from 'k6/http';
import { check, sleep } from "k6";
import { FormData } from 'https://jslib.k6.io/formdata/0.0.2/index.js';
import { open } from 'k6';
const imageFile = open('./src/captainRegistration/captain.png', 'b');
// Create form data for the file
let formData = new FormData();
formData.append('file', http.file(imageFile, 'captain.png', 'image/png'));


open is automatically available and needn't be imported. Trying to import a nonexistent symbol will set its value to undefined.
Your line
import { open } from 'k6';

is equivalent to
const open = undefined;

and that's going to fail, since you cannot invoke undefined.
Simply drop the import line and your test works.
Reference: https://grafana.com/docs/k6/latest/javascript-api/init-context/open/

This was very helpful its working now , thank u so much

@AsmaaAlNaanah What should I do when someone answers my question?. »Please do not add a comment on your question or on an answer to say "Thank you". […] If you want to say "thank you," vote on or accept that person's answer […]« Let future visitors know that the answer solved your problem by upvoting or by accepting it.
